# using orchard returns null when access Users

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

ok....So im clicking on 'Users' on the dashboard which navigates to

`Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Users/Views/Admin/index.cshtml`

which throws an error:

`Value cannot be null or empty.`

`Parameter name: linkText with the @Html.ActionLink(entry.User.UserName, "Edit", new { entry.User.Id })`

went through it with debug and `entry.user.Username` returns `null`. I've tried with a normal user and an admin logged in....not sure why or when this started happening last time I tried the users page was working....anyone know why?

```
Stack:

    at System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String linkText, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String linkText, String actionName, Object routeValues)
   at ASP._Page_Modules_Orchard_Users_Views_admin_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\WORK\BoireannSVN\trunk\VS\Orchard1.6.1\Orchard.Source\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.Users\Views\Admin\Index.cshtml:line 65
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.LayoutAwareViewEngine.<>c__DisplayClass7.<FindView>b__5(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, IViewDataContainer viewDataContainer) in C:\WORK\BoireannSVN\trunk\VS\Orchard1.6.1\Orchard.Source\src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\ThemeAwareness\LayoutAwareViewEngine.cs:line 59
   at Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.ThemeAwareness.LayoutAwareViewEngine.LayoutView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) in C:\WORK\BoireannSVN\trunk\VS\Orchard1.6.1\Orchard.Source\src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\ThemeAwareness\LayoutAwareViewEngine.cs:line 90
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

Comment: you need to look through your database, must be some funny user in there

Comment: but if im logged in with the as the original admin surely I should be fit to access Users

Comment: He means one of the users Orchard is trying to display might have a null or strange value in it. The logged in user is probably fine.

Comment: Ah yes I was adding dummy data entries for users earlier to test another matter and had someones username set to NULL.....thanks guys for helping